# "for" loop wildcard evaluated to variable if no such files present

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard

```
$ for f in /etc/shell*; do echo $f; done
/etc/shells
$
```

good!

```
$ for f in /etc/no_such*; do echo $f; done
/etc/no_such*
$
```

BAD!

How can I reap off wildcard evaluation if no files present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a specific shell option to enable this behaviour with globs, called `nullglob`. To enable it, use `shopt -s nullglob`.

When this option is enabled, a pattern with no matches evaluates to nothing, rather than to itself.

This is non-standard feature provided by bash, so if you're using another shell or are looking for a more widely compatible option you can add a condition to the loop body:

```
for f in /etc/no_such*; do [ -e "$f" ] && echo "$f"; done
```

This will only echo if the file exists.